# Appending columns to a file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a somewhat long awk script and I want to append two columns at the "right hand side" of the file. I have the following file in progress:

```
Node    temporary_Temperature   steady_Temperature  temporary_Sight steady_Sight    
1                   x                   x                   -                   -                   
2                   x                   x                   -                   -                   
3                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
4                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
5                   x                   x                   x                   -                   
6                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
7                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
8                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
9                   -                   -                   -                   -                   
10                  -                   -                   -                   -                   
11                  -                   -                   -                   -                   
12                  -                   -                   -                   -                   
13                  x                   x                   -                   -                   
14                  x                   x                   -                   -                   
15                  x                   -                   -                   -                   
16                  -                   -                   -                   -
```

The data are already written to a file and I want to iterate the lines in this file using awk and, let's say, append two more columns. At the header row I want to append the columns `foo` and `bar`, and thereafter append `x` or `-` to each line depending on other stuff. How can I achieve this? Since I am in the middle of a longer script I do not want to use sed unless there is some way to invoke sed from within an awk script amd print to the same file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you may face here is that whenever awk modifies fields, it re-writes your `$0`, replacing IFS with OFS.  If your FS is "any amount of whitespace" (the default FS), and it gets replaced with "a space" (the default OFS), you lose formatting.

To demonstrate:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'one    two\tthree\n'
one    two      three
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'one    two\tthree\n' | awk '{$4 = "four"} 1'
one two three four
```

If you don't really want to modify the *fields* of each line, and you just want to apend a string, you can do that without rewriting your field separators:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ printf 'one    two\tthree\n' | awk '{print $0 "\tfour"}'
one    two      three   four
```

Without seeing your script, or the kind of data you want to append, it's difficult for me to provide specific examples that I know will be applicable to your situation, but here's an example to get you started:

```
  NR == 1 {
    print $0 "\tfoo\tbar";
    next;
  }
  {
    print $0 "\t" (conditionone ? "x" : "-") "\t" (conditiontwo ? "x" : "-");
  }
```

If you need help crafting the conditions, please include them in your question.  I've used short-forms in the code above; you could obviously space things out and make multiple-line prints using `printf()`, or set variables based on the two conditions to be included in your `print`.

As an alternative, you could just re-do your formatting as you go through the input data.  For example (assuming the trailing spaces in your question are really what your input file looks like):

```
BEGIN {
  fmt="%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%s\n";
}

NR == 1 {
  printf("%s%12s%-20s%-20s\n", $0, " ", "foo", "bar");
  next;
}

{ foo="-"; bar="-"; }

conditionone { foo="x"; }
conditiontwo { bar="x"; }

{
  printf(fmt, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, foo, bar);
}
```

You'd probably have to fiddle with your spacing on line 1.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation; my awk skills have increased! My problem was actually a bit more complex than I managed to describe at the end of my working day. I am iterating fileA and printing to fileB (fileB is shown in the OP). Then I want to iterate fileC and print some resulting columns from there to file B. I actually ended up in printing two files and use `paste fileA fileC > fileB` and then removing file A and file C. Not very pretty, but it works. I'd appreciate any comments to this approach, and also accept your answer since it answers my original (poorly described) problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the formatting that's a problem, pipe the output through `column -t`

Example:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {print $0, "foo", "bar"; next} 
    {print $0, ($2=="x"?"-":"x"), ($4=="x"?"-":"x")}
' file | column -t
```

outputs

```
Node  temporary_Temperature  steady_Temperature  temporary_Sight  steady_Sight  foo  bar
1     x                      x                   -                -             -    x
2     x                      x                   -                -             -    x
3     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
4     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
5     x                      x                   x                -             -    -
6     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
7     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
8     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
9     -                      -                   -                -             x    x
10    -                      -                   -                -             x    x
11    -                      -                   -                -             x    x
12    -                      -                   -                -             x    x
13    x                      x                   -                -             -    x
14    x                      x                   -                -             -    x
15    x                      -                   -                -             -    x
16    -                      -                   -                -             x    x
```